# Why QT creator asks to install NDK 21.3?

Tags: android, qt-creator

I have NDK 23.1 installed:

[image]

but do not have Android QT versions installed in QT Creator, but only Windows versions:

[image]

so it is not clear what does "All essential packages installed for all installed Qt versions" on the picture above mean.

When I open Devices tab QT Creator asks to install the following components:

[image]

Why does it ask to install NDK 21.3, but not some other version? Does it assume that all Android QT versions depends on NDK 21.3?

Comment: because QT is C++ framework and prolly depends on given NDK version

Comment: @Selvin I have an impression that QT Creator assumes that all Android QT versions depends on NDK 21.3, but not some other version of NDK like 23.1, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are terribly annoying settings in `%SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Application Data\QtProject\sdk_definitions.json`:

```
        "versions": ["default"],
        "sdk_essential_packages": ["build-tools;30.0.2", "ndk;21.3.6528147"],
        "ndk_path": "ndk/21.3.6528147"
```